# C# OData Date only

Tags: c#, date, datetime, odata, datetimeoffset

I made an OData service that exposes some data from and Access Database, everything is working fine i am successfully reading the data.

On this link i found that OData supports "Edm.Date" which is a date only object type.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff478141.aspx

If i use DateTime or DateTimeOffset it includes time in the output and in the schematic (metadata) i see that it isn't of "Edm.Date" type.

After some google-in around i didn't find anything that would suggest that C# has "date only" object type.

I am using the default Visual Studio 2013 OData project template.

My question is, what object type do i need to use in C# so that it converts to "Edm.Date" in the OData service ?

Comment: Just use `DateTime`.  The result should have a "zero" time.

Comment: There's also an Edm.DateTimeOffset field which contains both date and time. Maybe you should just use that and not have to worry about the "date only" issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET Web API for OData V4 to write your service, the Edm.Date and Edm.TimeOfDay support will come in the next release (i.e. v5.5) in March.